# golang access values from map inside a map

Tags: dictionary, go

I am leveraging [Avi Go SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Crypto89/sdk/go@v0.0.0-20190910135836-56c48329b7ce#section-readme) to fetch avi healthmonitor configuration as below

```
var healthmonitormap map[string]interface{}
err = aviClient.AviSession.GetObjectByName("healthmonitor", "healthmonitorname", &healthmonitormap)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
```

Which store the metadata of health monitor in healthmonitormap as a map like below

```
map[
_last_modified:1644392621383838 
failed_checks:3 
https_monitor:map[
    http_request:GET /welcome HTTP/1.1 
    http_response_code:[HTTP_2XX HTTP_3XX]] 
monitor_port:443 
name:helloworldspringbootssl-dit1-monitor 
receive_timeout:3 
send_interval:10 
successful_checks:3 
tenant_ref:https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/tenant/tenant-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
type:HEALTH_MONITOR_HTTPS 
url:https://xxxxxxxxxxx/api/healthmonitor/healthmonitor-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
uuid:healthmonitor-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
```

From the map, I am able to successfully access name, monitor_port etc. Which are in the root of map as below

```
assert.Equal(t, healthmonitormap["name"], "helloworldspringbootssl-dit1-monitor")
assert.Equal(t, float64(443), healthmonitormap["monitor_port"])
```

However I am not able to understand how to access the things like http_request and http_response_code which are map inside a map.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the elem of the map is an `interface{}` you have to convert it to the corresponding type to access it as a map, like this:

```
if value, ok := healthmonitormap["https_monitor"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
    fmt.Println(value["http_request"]) //Output: GET /welcome HTTP/1.1 
}
```

Comment: I did `assert.Equal(t, healthmonitormap["https_monitor"].(map[string]interface{})["http_request"], "GET /welcome HTTP/1.1")` and that worked.  

I did `assert.Equal(t, healthmonitormap["https_monitor"].(map[string]interface{})["http_response_code"], "[HTTP_2XX HTTP_3XX]")`  for  http_response_code  and getting error  

`expected: []interface {}([]interface {}{"HTTP_2XX", "HTTP_3XX"})`  
`actual  : string("[HTTP_2XX HTTP_3XX]")`

Comment: if you get a chance, could you please look at above comment ?

Comment: As the error messages says, you have to provide an array as the third parameter. You provided a `string` instead. Try to use `[]string{"HTTP_2XX", "HTTP_3XX"}`